# How to keep track of user on my app and know when he/she goes offline/online?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am developing a simple chatting app with **Mongoose** (MongoDB) and **NodeJS** as my backend.

I have this Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    isActive: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true,
    }
}, {timestamps: true});
```

My problem is how should I update if the user is offline? should I define some routes to change that or how should I do it, please?

**I'm not sure if I designed the Schema correctly, especially the `isActive field`. you can suggest to me a better Schema as well**.

Thank you so much as you help me out!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can do it using socket.io**

Client-side you can fire emit with userId like

```
const socket = io();
socket.emit('online',{userId:'LoggedInUserId'});
```

Server-side

```
const onlineUsers = {};
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('online', function(data){
    onlineUsers[socket.id] = data.userId;
    const doc = await User.findOneAndUpdate({
        id: data.userId
    }, { isActive: true }, { upsert: true });
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    const oflineUserId = onlineUsers[socket.id];  
    const doc = await User.findOneAndUpdate({
        id: oflineUserId
    }, { isActive: false }, { upsert: true });
  });
});
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I was looking for but unfortunately I don't have experience with socket.io, I'm gonna watch some couple crash courses on YouTube before implementing it. Hopefully, I can come back to mark it correct answer. In the meantime, I upvoted it thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Well you should create a middleware that will set the status into cache.
Now define a function that will fetch the status of user from cache. And call this function in the parent layout.